# Separate a column into new columns based on the number of leading spaces

Tags: r, excel, whitespace, indentation, quickbooks

These reports are coming from [quickbooks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IANXs.png), downloaded as Excel files. Notice that the left column is this nested hierarchy based on the left spacing.

I need to separate *Description* column into separate columns based on the number of leading spaces on the left.

As I've been working with financial reports recently, these are super common and extremely difficult to work with. Is there a package or function for importing this type of data?

[image]

Here is example reproducible input *dataframe*:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Description = c("asset", " current asset", "   bank acc", 
                                      "    banner", "    clearing",
                                      "   total bank accounts",
                                      " total current assets"),
                 Total = c(NA, NA, NA, 10L, 20L, 30L, 30L)),
            .Names = c("Description", "Total"), 
            class = "data.frame", 
            row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: *"[leading indentations to signify multiple column hierarchy] are super common and extremely difficult to work with. Is there a package or function...*" Not for the indentation thing apparently, but you could raise an enhance request on tidyxl.

Comment: @smci Good idea, posted a [feature request](https://github.com/nacnudus/tidyxl/issues/41)

Comment: You probably need to restate the request in their github ticket; also to say that it occurs often in financial reports (Quickbooks? which other formats?). By the way, should the inferred columns be `Col1,Col2...` or do you want to give them names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `tidyxl` and `unpivotr` for these Excel wrangling tasks. Here are the docs:

- unpivotr: https://github.com/nacnudus/unpivotr
- tidyxl: https://nacnudus.github.io/tidyxl/

Here's a nice tutorial: https://blog.davisvaughan.com/2018/02/16/tidying-excel-cash-flow-spreadsheets-in-r/

Comment: Thank you, Matt!!! I could not figure this one out for a week. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the real question is:

- **"How do I treat number of leading spaces to indicate *nth* column?"**

If so, then try this example, code could be improved, but the idea is every leading space indicates *nth* column.

```
# example input, we will have similar input after reading in
# the Excel sheet into R.
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("x1", " x2", " x2", "  x3", "x1", " x2"),
                  y = c(NA,      22,    33,      44,   55,   66),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

cbind(
  bind_rows(
  lapply(df1$x, function(i){
    x <- data.frame(t(strsplit(i, split = " ")[[1]]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    colnames(x) <- paste0("col", 1:ncol(x))
    x
    })
  ),
  df1[, "y", drop = FALSE])

#   col1 col2 col3  y
# 1   x1 <NA> <NA> NA
# 2        x2 <NA> 22
# 3        x2 <NA> 33
# 4             x3 44
# 5   x1 <NA> <NA> 55
# 6        x2 <NA> 66
```

Comment: I think you're completely right. Still have to figure out whether the above mentioned packages tackle this directly, otherwise, this is a great solution. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Super_John Great, that is what I thought. I edited your post with simplified reproducible input example. Hope that will attract better answers.